# Should I use a single stud mount or a mount spaced 12" or a mount spaced 24" inch?

Tags: mounting, studs

I am trying to mount a 49 inch TV but I am having some issues. In the image provided, if I mount TV between studs 1 and 3, some part of the TV goes out of the area. I am struggling to find a TV mount which are 12" apart. My personal preference is not to use a single stud mount because Physics wise, I am not sure putting that much weight on a single stud is a good thing . My questions,

1. Is it ok to use a single stud mount? Especially if I want the swivel one and not the tilt ones.
2. Should I still try to mount between stud 1 & 3 or should I continue to look for mounts that fit the studs between 2 & 3?

[image]

Comment: Or painted to match the set, I think. Haven't tried it so that's a guess.

Comment: @crip659 Write that up and +1

Comment: You mean that the mounts have fabricated holes that are spaced at 16" and/or 24", but nothing spaced at 12"? Drilling holes in metal is easy with the correct drill bit. It'll say "metal" on the packaging. The cuttings can stick to your shoe and scratch hardwoods, for instance, so there's just some tidiness involved. Get a mount with enough heft at your chosen screw positions so that you can confidently fabricate new screw holes. Link your candidate mounts if you want more specific input.

Comment: Hopefully the bottom of the TV will be above the switches...

Answer (score 1):

A single stud should hold the weight.

If you want more peace of mind, can use two studs or a piece of 3/4 inch plywood/1x4s/2x4s mounted on different studs to give exact mounting position, if the studs are not in the right place.

The wood can be painted to match the wall or the mount. Plus one to @keshlam. Or be stained for a nice wood look.

Answer (score 0):

With a modern 49 inch TV, wood studs, proper screws correctly installed and a fixed mount, *not a swivel one*, a single stud mount is fine.

If you have metal studs, a heavy old TV, or if you use a swivel mount or do anything that will invite people to handle the TV regularly, do not use a single stud mount.

Otherwise I don't understand the question about stud #1.  Various methods of using #2 and #3 to put the TV where you want it should work nicely with 4 screws in 2 studs.  It can cantilever out slightly over the alcove.

Drill carefully to avoid piercing cables. You probably have a couple of cables running up or down along stud #1 for the switches.

Comment: The stuff about stud #1, I think, is because stud #1 to stud #3 is 24", and lots of mounts exist for the 24" since it's a standard spacing. I guess a mount fabricated for a custom spacing like 12" is difficult to find? Maybe the marketing people don't adequately describe all of the holes fabricated in their products?

Comment: Idk about hole marketing ;). The problem with stud #1 is you probably can't move the TV far enough to the right. With studs two and three the right side of the mount will be hanging out over the alcove, not the best idea but with a small TV it's fine.